# Dovecot quota-warning.sh executed when I delete message

Tags: dovecot

```
plugin {
  quota_rule = *:storage=10M
  quota          = maildir:User quota
  quota_rule2     = Junk:ignore
  quota_rule3    = Trash:storage=+100M
  quota_warning = storage=50%% quota-warning 50 %u
  quota_exceeded = storage=100%% quota-exceeded 100 %u
}

plugin {
  quota_warning = storage=50%% quota-warning 50 %u
  quota_exceeded = storage=100%% quota-exceeded 100 %u
}

service quota-warning {
  executable = script /root/bin/quota-warning.sh
  user = root
  unix_listener quota-warning {
    user = vmail
    mode = 0666
  }
}

service quota-exceeded {
  executable = script /root/bin/quota-exceeded.sh
  user = root
  unix_listener quota-exceeded {
    user = vmail
    mode = 0666
  }
}
```

I sent an email with 8Mb (limit is 10Mb) but quota-warning executed when I delete that message (moved it to trash) instead of quota-exceeded being executed.

```
cat /root/bin/quota-warning.sh
touch /tmp/quota-warning-executed
cat /root/bin/quota-exceeded.sh
touch /tmp/quota-exceeded-executed
```

Comment: How can you tell which one ran?  Both scripts are identical.

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure quota exclusion for `Junk` folder and overhead for `Trash`:

```
plugin {
  quota          = maildir:User quota
  quota_rule     = Junk:ignore
  quota_rule2    = Trash:storage=+100M
  quota_warning  = storage=50%% quota-warning 50 %u
  quota_exceeded = storage=100%% quota-exceeded 100 %u
}
```

As stated by `dovecot` wiki, to avoid quota warning on moving to `Trash`,

> You can create a separate quota rule giving Trash mailbox somewhat
>   higher quota limit (but not unlimited)

That is intended because moving to the `Trash` is the two-step procedure (copying + removing). For the short time you have two copies of the same message and both of them are counted by quota plugin. If `Trash` have some overhead then freshly copied message do not exceed the main limit. Refer to the dovecot's wiki for further information: https://wiki.dovecot.org/Quota

Comment: thanks for your reply but I've same problem :/ Also adding "maildir:User quota"

Comment: Do not use `quota-warning` for 100% filled up mailbox. It's too late. Good points to send a warnings are 75% and 90%. Try to restart `dovecot` with modified config.

Comment: quota-warning is setted to 50%

Comment: `quota-exceeded` message is sent by LDA to the original sender when there is no room to store incoming message. When message is moved across the folders `quota-exceeded` event do not occur.

Comment: I made other tests but quota-warning works ONLY when I delete the message. Any advice? Thanks